# Creating Image (from uploaded VHD) is failing on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create a VM on Azure, from VHD of an On Premise Server. As per the steps, I have created the VHD file of the C Drive of my server (including the system reserved partition), and have uploaded the same VHD to Blob Storage (as Page Blob). I have uploaded it through Portal.

Now as per next step, I am trying to create an Image from it, so that it can be used to create VM.

But I am getting the following error:

> Failed to create image 'NewImage'. Error: At least one resource
>   deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
>   details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.

Not able to identify the actual error or problem in this.

Comment: Which steps do you follow? Do you install the Azure agent in the OS before you create the VHD file?

Comment: Hi Charles, I used disk2vhd sysinternal tool to create the VHD file for the C: drive (also including the system reserved partition). It was around 12.7 GB. Then uploaded the same VHD file to Azure Blob Storage Container (as Page Blob) - uploaded via Upload button on the portal. And no, I am not aware of this step for installing some Azure Agent on the OS. Did I missed something? Can you please explain what went wrong? And link to install the agent you suggesting?

Comment: I dig down the activity log, and found the following error: "Invalid Parameter : 
Only blobs formatted as VHDs can be imported." But I created VHD file only, still it is showing as invalid?

Comment: The agent is used to communicate with the VM and provide some feathers for troubling. See my answer below and take a try, it can help you.

Comment: Any update for the question? Please let me know if there is any update.

Comment: Hi Charles, I am currently working on it. Following the pre-steps for preparing the VHD. Will update when its done. Also, I dont want to use sysprep for this. Can I still use the disk2vhd tool?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just make sure the VHD file is available.

Comment: So current update is, my VM was on vmware vsphere, followed the steps as in the online document, and generated .vhdx file and transfered it to my local PC. Here, I was able to configure a VM on my local PC on Hyper V and it was successful. So I suppose it should work on Azure as well. I have now converted it to .vhd using powershell (fixed size disk) and uploading it to Azure. It will take time to upload.

Answer (score 2):

From description i believe the issue is with the way you converted the VHD.  People always miss the section where is says the VHD must be **Fixed Size** VHD.

Not sure if disk2vhd has the option but you can use the Convert-VHD command in Hyper-V module or [Microsoft VM Converter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497).

`Convert-VHD –Path c:\test\MY-VM.vhdx –DestinationPath c:\test\MY-NEW-VM.vhd -VHDType Fixed`

Also, VHD images on Azure must have a virtual size aligned to 1 MB. Typically, VHDs created using Hyper-V are aligned correctly.

Comment: This is really useful and currently also my mistake. However, this is a really painful limitation when you are forced to upload a big vhd image as fixed disk.

Answer (score 0):

To create the Azure VM from a VHD file which created on-premise. You need to do a lot of steps to prepare the VHD file. Not just convert the disk to the VHD file, you need to make sure it can run well on-premise.

The error you get does not show the reason that causes the accident. What I can provide are the steps that you can follow to create an available VHD file. And all the steps and recommends in [Prepare a Windows VHD or VHDX to upload to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: I was able to create the Image from the VHD file, but still VM creation is failing with following error: Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'MyFirstVM' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image: * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ *

Comment: @ShauryaS So, what about now? Which way do you use and do you succeed?

Comment: I was able to create the Image from the VHD file, used the same steps to create the VHD file as per the document, and converted into fixed size, and then upload to Blob Storage. I was successful creating the Image from the VHD file, but when trying to create a VM using that Image, its failing with the above said message. I'm stuck again!

Comment: @ShauryaS Do you try the create the VM with attaching the VHD file as the error show? Also, can you create vm from the VHD file in hyper-v locally?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create the VM using the 'Custom Image' that I created from my VHD file. And the error came. And yes, I was able to create the VM locally using the VHDX file (before converting it to VHD). Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ShauryaS No, but I suggest you could create VM from the VHD file locally after converting.

Comment: Does HyperV supports VHD image to create VM? I am assuming it required VHDX file?

Comment: Yes, I am able to create VM locally on HyperV with VHD file and is booting up properly.

Comment: @ShauryaS OK, then do you generalize the image with Sysprep?

Comment: No, using disk2vhd.

Comment: @ShauryaS You can take a look at another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272627/creating-azure-vm-from-custom-image) which shows the same error without generalized.

Comment: @ShauryaS What about now? Do you succeed?

Comment: @ShauryaS Do you mean it also fails to create VM from the image after generalizing the image with Sysprep?

Comment: Not yet, working on it still, with Microsoft Support.